# Finish Setting Up For Android?

Tags: android, android-ndk, haxe, haxeflixel, haxelib

So I am trying to install and setup to be an Android develop following this helpful video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VLUDui3VuGk

I got a few easily fixable errors then I got this one:

```
arm-linux-androideabi-g++: error: C:\android-ndk-r12b-windows-x86_64\android-ndk-r12b\/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9/libgcc.a: No such file or directory
Error: error running arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -olibApplicationMain-v7.so -frtti -nostdlib -std=c++11 -Wl,-shared,-Bsymbolic -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack --sysroot=C:\android-ndk-r12b-windows-x86_64\android-ndk-r12b\/platforms/android-9/arch-arm -LC:\android-ndk-r12b-windows-x86_64\android-ndk-r12b\/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/lib @obj/android-v7/all_objs C:\android-ndk-r12b-windows-x86_64\android-ndk-r12b\/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi/libgnustl_static.a C:\android-ndk-r12b-windows-x86_64\android-ndk-r12b\/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o C:\android-ndk-r12b-windows-x86_64\android-ndk-r12b\/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9/libgcc.a C:\android-ndk-r12b-windows-x86_64\android-ndk-r12b\/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/lib/libc.so C:\android-ndk-r12b-windows-x86_64\android-ndk-r12b\/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/lib/libm.so -llog -ldl
Build halted with errors (haxelib.exe).
```

Okay fine. I thought. So another hour or so of downloads more. What's another? Then I got to THIS page:

https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain.html

And I am absolutely lost and have no idea how to follow the instructions provided at all.

Can someone possibly walk me through this next step please?

Answer (score 1):

Did you check if file available and search path where it placed

> C:\android-ndk-r12b-windows-x86_64\android-ndk-r12b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9/libgcc.a

Comment: The file is there if that is what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Im install NDK and folder
/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/**4.9.x/**
has renamed to
/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/**4.9/**
and all works!!!
;-)

Answer (score 0):

Copy folder 4.9.x to 4.9, solved my problem.
(Renaming was not enough for me: show me more linking errors... Other files need 4.9 and 4.9.x folder...)